# Intergraph G-Technology Generating relationships

Tags: relates, intergraph

I have tried generating relationships on Intergraph G-Technology but every time it gets to 30, it comes up saying 0 features successfully generated relationships and at the bottom left, it says please check log for more info. The AutoCAD file has no errors on it, so I know its not that, it must be a G-Technology issue, but I have no idea what the problem is. Does anyone know what I can do? Where can I access the log info?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.